# Clock in java independent of system date and time

Tags: java, clock

I have application which stores received UDP packets in file, with storing receive time of each packet along with each packet. I am using `System.currentTimeMillies()` to get receive time when packet is received.

I need to store time, so because, when I transmit this file on UDP, I will transmit each packets from file, synchronizing with time stored for each packet.

The problem is, if I change system date and time while receiving and storing packets, synchronization while sending file gets messed up.

So I need timestamping each received packet independent of system date and time. So that while sending, sending rate will be synchronized even if system date and time was changed while receiving.

I know these can be achieved with `System.nanoTime()`, but is it safe to use this? I think `System.nanoTime()` may not be accurate over different system architecture and operating systems.

Also, if I use `System.nanoTime()`, how this clock will start (initial value), because I do not want it to end with last value while program is running. If from the first call to `System.nanoTime()` clock starts from 0, this clock can run for around 290 years before ending with last value.

Is there any alternative to `System.nanoTime()`? I need accuracy of clock in milliseconds.

Also I need this clock to run independent of system, because I may be transmitting file from other machine. Also, it should not skew time for days or months, never between different systems.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put the sent date inside your UDP packets ?

Comment: The application which sends UDP, is not in my control. I can't modify that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` is the only way (within the JDK) to get a date that won't change if your system's date is changed.

To deal with overflows (assuming your system will run less than 290 years), use an arbitrary starting point and store differences:

```
public static final long START = System.nanoTime();

//when receiving packet:
long date = System.nanoTime();
packet.setTimestamp(date - START);
```

Comment: Will System.nanoTime() be accurate over different machines? Because I may be sending file from different machine, other than from which file is created.

Comment: Program may be running for months to send file, from any machine. So, I need perfect clock.

Comment: No `System.nanoTime` is machine specific. If you need a "perfect clock" you could rely on a NTP server. Alternativele, if what matters is the order of the packets, you could simply have a server provide a auto-incrementing id.

Comment: NTP server can't be solution, I need this to be accurate in millies. I need timestamps to synchronize transmission rate as it was when file is received.